# How to copy host vector to device vector by thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I want to copy host `std::vector` to `thrust::device_vector`

```
std::vector<double> p_a(100)
thrust::device_vector<double> d_vec
```

I want to copy `p_a` to `d_vec`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documention](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1device__vector.html#a6925a9dc896b383edb35a6c340e1feb3),

You can use this constructor:

```
__host__ thrust::device_vector< T, Alloc >::device_vector   
(   const std::vector< OtherT, OtherAlloc > &   v   )
```

> Copy constructor copies from an exemplar `std::vector`.

This constructor receives as parameter the `std::vector` to copy.
So, you can do:

```
std::vector<double> p_a(100);
thrust::device_vector<double> d_vec(p_a);
```

And also you can use Copy-assignment:

```
d_vec = p_a;
```

Comment: Copy-assignment can also be used, as can thrust::copy

Comment: @talonmies Yes, added to the answer body!